# The scroll area of my bootstrap modal have an offset on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I all,

I am using modals on my website and the scroll area containing them do not fit the page.
See on the screenshot.

I am not applying any additional style to the modals and I can't figure out where does the problem come from.

I am sorry it is hard to post code because I am not sure which part might cause this and the code base is relatively large..[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: Sample modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addSpotModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick='addSpot.cancel()'
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add a spot</h4>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-body">


            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick='addSpot.cancel()'>Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='addSpot.sendAddSpotRequest()'>Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea?
Thanks. Olivier

[image]

Comment: What Bootstrap version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the scroll is based on the modal itself, so as you can see, the rounded corners are not visible. The content inside the modal is pushing the size to be larger than the viewing area. You could try the size utilities like `modal-lg` on the dialog (`<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">`) if you haven't done so. You can also change the dimensions through LESS/variables. The `@modal-lg`, `@modal-md`, and `@modal-sm`. To decrease the top margin, you would need to adjust the CSS for `modal-dialog` as 30px is the default.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I am using `modal-lg` and it is ok that that content of the modal is bigger than the page and that the user have to scroll to see all content. However, when I scroll part of the modal disappears on top (see screenshot in update question). Maybe something with the navbar?

Comment: It's impossible to debug something like that without relevant code. If I had to guess, I would say it has something to do with that nav menu. It looks like it might actually be overlaying (z-index too high) since it's not greyed out and the entire top modal is literally cut.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's hard, Thanks for the help, I will come back if I have identified a more precise problem!

Comment: Did you see if the z-index is higher than default (default is 1000) for the nav?

Comment: I removed the nag-fixed-top class on the navbar, then the navbar is grayed out but the modal is still hidden on top. Sorry I cannot be more precise but it actually helps debugging ;)

Comment: The problem came from some hidden ugly css actually. Thanks for taking the time to help!